# How can I setup an alias for a website in Webmatrix?

Tags: iis, webmatrix, iis-express

I have a site setup in webmatrix that runs on http://localhost:port on my local dev machine. At the moment I'm using a piece of open source software that is dependant on having a domain: http://localhost/alias

How can I set this up in Webmatrix? If it can't be done, what alternatives do I have?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, which piece of software are you trying to set up?  Is this something inside of the App Gallery?

Comment: Nah it was a bespoke digital asset manager

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do it directly using WebMatrix, but you can do it manually by editing %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config file or by using appcmd.exe located in the IIS Express installation folder (by adding an application to your site that points to your open source app).

**Option-1:**

1. Start command prompt and goto IIS Express installation folder
2. Run following command

   appcmd.exe add app /site.name:"site-name" /path:/alias /physicalPath:"full-path-of-the-app"

**Option-2:**
1. Open applicationhost.config file

1. Locate your 'site' in applicationhost.config file under 'sites' element
2. Add a new application element similar to below given entry

   ```
       <application path="/alias">
           <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="application-full-path" />
       </application>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but in the end I just setup IIS 7 on my local machine and did it that way